# Display Output Data for conversion between 2 Classes

Tags: c++, c++17

I implemented a conversion for feet to Meters as noted below but I am unable to print out the results in my main. Below is the code generating the error in

```
    Ftr cnum1(2);
    Mtr cnum2 = cnum1.toMtr();
    std::cout << cnum1.getNum() <<" feet = " << cnum2.getMtrNum() << " meters \n\n";
```

I’m unable to use the getNum method with cnum2 because getNum is not a method in Mtr. However the results can be accurately displayed in the Ftr.cpp file

```
#include "Ftr.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace fun::calc 

{
    Ftr::~Ftr() { }

    Ftr::Ftr(double Ftr) noexcept { }

    double Ftr::getNum() const noexcept { return m_Num;}

    Mtr Ftr::toMtr() const noexcept { return Mtr(m_Num * fInMtr); }
```

The Ftr header file contains the following:

```
#ifndef __FTR_H
#define __FTR_H
#include <cstdint>
#include “Mtr.h”

namespace fun::calc 
{
 
class Mtr;  
class Ftr
    {  
        double m_Num;
static constexpr double fInMtr = 0.3048;
    public:
        Ftr() = delete;
        explicit Ftr(double Ftr) noexcept;
        ~Ftr() noexcept;
        Ftr(const Ftr &other) = default;
        Ftr(Ftr &&other) = default;

        double getNum() const noexcept;
        Ftr operator+(const Ftr &rhs) const;
        Mtr toMtr() const noexcept;       
    };
}
#endif;
```

I tried to create a getMtrNum function in the Mtr.cpp as follows:

```
    double Meters:: getMtrNum () const noexcept { return m_mtr;}
```

I modified main() to use getMtrNum as shown below

```
Ftr cnum1(2);
    Mtr cnum2 = cnum1.toMtr();
    std::cout << cnum1.getNum() <<" feet = " << cnum2.getMtrNum() << " meters \n\n";
```

The results now display 0.0 because n_mtr is initialized to 0.0 in the Mtr.h file
The output produced is :
2 feet = 0 meters
Any suggestions on how to implement this to get the correct results displayed outside of the function definition? Ideally I would like to generate the correct results without having to create getMtrNum. Please provide some guidance on the proper way to get data flowing between the 2 different classes and display the results properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, there are two points you would like to do:

1. Fix the code so it shows the conversion value
2. Make the print without creating getMtrNum()

For the second point, if you want to keep your member private, you will need to create a getter/printer function in any case. Probably a bit more elegant if you create an ostream "<<" operator overload. In this way you don't need to use getter function during printing Meters.

**Edit**: To be more precise getter is still used. Once in the operator overload

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Meters& m)
{
  out << m.Get();
  return out;
}

// in main
// std::cout << cnum1.Get() <<" feet = " << cnum2 << " meters \n\n";
```

A complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Meters {
public:
  Meters(const Meters& m)
    :m_Meters(m.m_Meters)
  {
  }
  Meters(double m)
    :m_Meters(m)
  {
  }

  double Get() const { return m_Meters; }
private:
  double m_Meters{};
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Meters& m)
{
  out << m.Get();
  return out;
}

class Feet{
public:
  Feet(double f)
  : m_Feet(f)
  {}

  static constexpr double fInMtr = 0.3048;
  Feet() = default;

  Meters ToMeters() const { return Meters(m_Feet * fInMtr); }
  double Get() const { return m_Feet; }

private:
  double m_Feet{};
};

int main()
{
  Feet cnum1(2);
  Meters cnum2 = cnum1.ToMeters();
  std::cout << cnum1.Get() <<" feet = " << cnum2 << " meters \n\n";
}
```

I hope, this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Adding the <<" operator overload was key.

Comment: You are most welcome. If it answers your question, please click on the little check mark underneath the up vote count to accept the answer and complete the question.